# Git log --graph file list per commit

Tags: git

Is that possible to add under each node in the `git log --graph` the list of files affected by the commit?

*I always have multiple commits that I need to push, and instead looking one by one in order to see affected files (files that I am going to push), I would love to get a quick overview of the tree with this information.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log --graph --stat`

Reference: [git-log(1) Manual Page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Comment: That's awesome! adding this to the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs: `git log --graph --stat --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Add the `--name-only` flag. For example:

```
git log --graph --name-only
```

### Man Page

The git-log(1) man page says:

```
--name-only
    Show only names of changed files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --numstat
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use GUI based application to see such thing.

I am currently using "git g" application which gives complete idea of

change file with showing the line which changed,
showing list of files changed,
option to see code in particular commit, etc.

You can installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install gitg
```

I am attaching snapshot of application.

[image]